# Code Syntax Highlighting for [mariadb] tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

The default code syntax highlighting for the [mariadb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mariadb) tag should be same as that of the [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) tag. But it is not auto-formatting as of now.

For eg: [Extracting data several relations deep. Parent, children, sub-children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53175236/extracting-data-several-relations-deep-parent-children-sub-children)

Please add prettify for [mariadb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mariadb) tag as well.

Comment: It makes sense that what's right for [tag:mysql] should be right for [tag:mariadb].  +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've set the default code language for the [mariadb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mariadb) tag to match that of [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql): `lang-sql`.